# How do I compile this Fortran code with new 2017 ifort?

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, intel-fortran

I have the following fortran code that compiles with pre 2017 ifort:

```
program parallel_m
contains
   character(500) function PARALLEL_message(i_ss)
     character(50)    :: Short_Description = " "
     integer :: i_s =0 
     integer :: n_threads = 0 
     !
     PARALLEL_message=" "
     !
     if (i_s>0) then
       if (len_trim("test this ")==0) return
     endif
     !
     if (i_s==0) then
       PARALLEL_message=trim("10")//"(CPU)"
       if (n_threads>0) PARALLEL_message=trim(PARALLEL_message)//"-"//trim("200")//"(threads)"
     else
       PARALLEL_message=trim("a")//"(environment)-"//&
      &                 trim("a")//"(CPUs)-"//&
      &                 trim("a")//"(ROLEs)"
     endif
     !
   end function
end program parallel_m
```

Going through the preprocessor :

```
icc -ansi -E  example.F  > test.f90
```

Which produces:

```
# 1 "mod.F"
program parallel_m
contains
   character(500) function PARALLEL_message(i_ss)
     character(50)    :: Short_Description = " "
     integer :: i_s =0 
     integer :: n_threads = 0 
     !
     PARALLEL_message=" "
     !
     if (i_s>0) then
       if (len_trim("test this ")==0) return
     endif
     !
     if (i_s==0) then
       PARALLEL_message=trim("10")
       if (n_threads>0) PARALLEL_message=trim(PARALLEL_message)
     else
       PARALLEL_message=trim("a")
      &                 trim("a")
      &                 trim("a")
     endif
     !
   end function
end program parallel_m
```

This unfortunately with intel 2017 does not compile, the same
output compiles without complaint on 2016 and 2015 ifort releases.
this is the error that I  get:

```
mod.F(19): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; TYPE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX BYTE CHARACTER CLASS DOUBLE ...
      &                 trim("a")
------------------------^
mod.F(20): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; TYPE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX BYTE CHARACTER CLASS DOUBLE ...
      &                 trim("a")
------------------------^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

Comment: Your preprocessor is the problem, it is stripping off the continuation ampersand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is illegal Fortran after the preprocessing because the `//` is interpretted as a C comment.

Simply do not use `icc` but `ifort`. `Ifort` is for Fortran, `icc` is for C. `Ifort` uses a different preprocessor `fpp` which does not discard `//`.

Comment: How would that commandline look like?  with  `ifort -fpp -o mod.x mod.F`  it  gives errors

Comment: That is another problem. Rename to `.F90` or use  `-free`. `.F` means fixed form.

Comment: perfect. this will do