# Syntax error for a Fortran code with gfortran 4.9.2

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am running the following command to compile a Fortran code

```
gfortran -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-0 -ff2c -fno-second-underscore -I/opt/fftw-3.3.5/include -O3 -c xml.f90 -I/opt/openmpi-2.0.1/include -pthread -I/opt/openmpi-2.0.1/lib
xml.F:641.46:

       CALL XML_TAG("set", comment="spin "
                                          1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

That line is

```
CALL XML_TAG("set", comment="spin "//TRIM(ADJUSTL(strcounter)))
```

It seems that the code is compatible Fortran. I don't know which version, but currently, gfortran is 4.9.2 (ubuntu 15.04). How can I fix that?

Comment: I imagine the caveat mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38953616) is related: I see your file has the suffix `.F` suggesting cpp is run on the file first, and that sees `//` as a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112130/how-do-i-compile-this-fortran-code-with-new-2017-ifort But the focus is slightly elsewhere.

Comment: -cpp option needed if you didn't observe the .F convention which doesn't  work on some OS e.g. Windows