# Illegal character in statement label field - when compiling .f extension

Tags: annotations, fortran, intel-fortran

I tried to compile **.f** files using ifort.

I got following errors:

**/.../wreqvr.f(2): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [h]
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
----^**

From the following suggestion:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/293662
-> says that changing the extension .f to .f90 works.

Is there any other solution? (I don't want to change the extension because the code is managed by git...)

I used the same ifort version for my old machine which works well without error.

I don't understand why this error comes out.

The only difference between my old machine and new machine is the centos version (old 6, new 7)

Does the gcc version matter regarding this error?

---

I added part of the code and error msg. here: coord.f file

```
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */


/* This header is separate from features.h so that the compiler can
   include it implicitly at the start of every compilation.  It must
   not itself include <features.h> or any other header that includes
   <features.h> because the implicit include comes before any feature
   test macros that may be defined in a source file before it first
   explicitly includes a system header.  GCC knows the name of this
   header in order to preinclude it.  */

/* We do support the IEC 559 math functionality, real and complex.  */

/* wchar_t uses ISO/IEC 10646 (2nd ed., published 2011-03-15) /
   Unicode 6.0.  */

/* We do not support C11 <threads.h>.  */

      subroutine coord(vx,vy,n,d,x,y)

c  version : 21.07.2000 16:18
c=======================================================================
      implicit none
c*** Calculate the x and y coordinates of a point located on a curve v
c*** at a distance d from the origin of the curve

*  arguments
      integer n
      real*8 vx(n),vy(n),d,x,y

*  variables locales
      integer i
      real*8 dist,distot,eps
      parameter (eps=1.e-06)

*  procedures
      intrinsic sqrt

c========================
c.. n   : number of points in the curve
c.. vx,vy: coordinates of the points in the curve
c.. d   : required distance along the curve
c.. x,y : coordinates of the found point
c.. dist: distance between 2 consecutive points on the curve
c.. distot: total distance covered
c========================

*..Initialisation.

      distot = 0.0

*..Loop over the curve segments

      do i=1, n-1 !{

         dist = sqrt((vx(i+1)-vx(i))**2 + (vy(i+1)-vy(i))**2)
         distot = distot + dist

*..Check whether the distance d is passed

         if (distot .ge. d) then !{
            x = vx(i+1) - ((distot-d)/dist)*(vx(i+1)-vx(i))
            y = vy(i+1) - ((distot-d)/dist)*(vy(i+1)-vy(i))

            return

         end if !}

      end do  !}
c*** Check whether the required distance is equal - within tolerance -
c*** to the total curve length

      if (abs(distot - d) .lt. eps) then !{
         x = vx(n)
         y = vy(n)

         return

      end if !}

*..Error: required distance greater than the total curve length.

      print *, 'coord: required distance greater than the total length'
      print*,'distot=',distot
      print*,'d=',d
      call pltend
      stop  'Check the target specification'

      end
```

---

$ ifort coord.f

```
coord.f(1): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [/]
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
^
coord.f(1): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [*]
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
-^
coord.f(1): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [C]
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
---^
coord.f(1): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [o]
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
----^
coord.f(1): error #5118: First statement in file must not be continued
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
-----^
coord.f(2): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [T]
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
---^
coord.f(2): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [h]
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
----^
coord.f(4): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [T]
   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
---^
coord.f(4): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [h]
   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
```

---

$ ifort -free coord.f
or
$ ifort coord.f90

```
coord.f(1): error #5082: Syntax error, found '/' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; BLOCK BLOCKDATA PROGRAM MODULE TYPE BYTE CHARACTER ...
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
^
coord.f(16): error #5145: Invalid blank/tab
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */
----------------------------------^
coord.f(20): error #5145: Invalid blank/tab
   include it implicitly at the start of every compilation.  It must
-----------------------------------------------------------^
coord.f(29): error #5143: Missing mandatory separating blank
/* wchar_t uses ISO/IEC 10646 (2nd ed., published 2011-03-15) /
--------------------------------^
coord.f(30): error #5145: Invalid blank/tab
   Unicode 6.0.  */
---------------^
```

Comment: So did you verify that changing the extension works or not? Where is the code? See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: In Intol Fortran use `-free` to force fixed source form (the .f90 one).

Comment: *"Does the gcc version matter regarding this error?"* This has nothing to do with GCC...

Comment: Part of the code:
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.  */

Error msg:
coord.f(1): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [/]
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
^
coord.f(1): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [*]
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
-^
...
Annotation gives error.

Comment: I changed the extension to f90 and adding -free option.
Then the errors regarding /* annotations are gone.

However, different error comes out:

part of the code:
c.. n   : number of points in the curve

coord.f90(56): error #5145: Invalid blank/tab
c.. n   : number of points in the curve
---^

Also annotation related (c..)

I changed the ifort version from 17.0.2, 16.0.3, 12.1.6 (old machine used this ifort version, still totally working for the same code) but all of them gives error.

** I should read asking rules more carefully, sorry for that.
Thanks for your help

Comment: We can't say anything without seeing the code. Note that tabs should not be used in any Fortran source.

Comment: that code needs to be run through a preprocesor to remove the c style comments  (or you could manually edit it out if its just that stuff at the top)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112130/how-do-i-compile-this-fortran-code-with-new-2017-ifort  where did you get that file? Ifort will not put there those lines on its own. I supposed something like this from the beginning, but you are not telling us the full story. **Show us the ORIGINAL code and all commands you execute!**

Comment: I attached the full code. This code is part of CFD simulation. It looks that I need C pre-processing. Maybe the main code do the pre-precessing but in the old machine everything worked well even though I didn't set anything.

Comment: If that is *really* the original ten just delete the offending C comments. They look line an output of a preprocessor used before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compile this Fortran code with new 2017 ifort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112130/how-do-i-compile-this-fortran-code-with-new-2017-ifort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are the original files you are compiling then you should delete the C style comments.

They begin with `/*` and end with `*/`.

These blocks are not legal Fortran. C preprocessor discards them, but even if you enable pre-processing by `ifort -fpp` they will not be discarded. Only the C pre-processor discards them.

See also [How do I compile this Fortran code with new 2017 ifort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112130/how-do-i-compile-this-fortran-code-with-new-2017-ifort) for a similar problem.

It is almost certain that someone created those files by using the C preprocessor before. And that is wrong. Don't use the C preprocessor on its own for Fortran source files.

And don't use `gcc` to preprocess Fortran sources, it is a C preprocessor and it uses the C preprocessor in a wrong mode. You can use the preprocessor through Fortran compilers (`gfortran -cpp` or `ifort -fpp` - be careful cpp and fpp slightly differ), but don't use the C preprocessor directly and don't use C compilers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
As you answered, there are C preprocessing steps using gcc in my code package.
The gcc version in Centos 7 is different from Centos 6.
Due to this version difference, preprocessing is not correctly performed in new gcc so that C style comments has left.
gcc version change fixed this problem.
(or changing OS to older version which has older version of gcc...)
gcc 4.8.5 doesn't work.
gcc 4.4.7 works.

Comment: It is the version of the C preprocessor that matters, not GCC itself. You can do preprocessing by `fpp` or `ifort -fpp` or `gfortran -cpp` and there will be no C comments. And remember when I asked whether it is **really the original** code?...

Comment: The original code extension is .F
It has the same contents except the /* */ parts at first. It starts from subroutine coord...

Comment: So you did not show thee original even if I asked you several times. Did you even read the link I provided? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112130/how-do-i-compile-this-fortran-code-with-new-2017-ifort

Comment: Sorry for that. I thought .f file is original at first. Due to many dependencies for setting up old C preprocessor, I setup centos 6.8 which contains old C preprocessor. Now problem has solved.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this has been answered, I just ran into the same issue.
What helped is this tread and also this: 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/293662 (even though I'm on linux)

The combination of .f90 and the usage if ifort instead of f77 helped.

If the build system relies on setting FC, F77, etc. (also MPIF77) make sure to set them to ifort (and mpiifort) accordingly.
If different sub-steps default to different tools for consecutive tasks you generally run into issues, so rather control them explicitly, according to your build system.